# send subview to the back

Tags: iphone, uiview, subview

I know of a function that brings a view to the front.

```
  [self.view bringSubviewToFront:myView];
```

I am wondering if there is a function that sends a subview to the back.

Comment: I believe it literally is called `-sendSubviewToBack:`.  LOL

Comment: ahah, sorry, yes, I just found it as you responded...  thanks anyways!

Comment: pretty sure it's directly below it in the docs.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Try,

**Objective-C:**

```objectivec
[self.view sendSubviewToBack: yourView];
```

**Swift:**

```swift
self.view.sendSubview(toBack: yourView)
```